# Creating AVG query with Peewee in Python

Tags: python, orm, peewee

Im using Peewee ORM. I have only one table (Person) with fields like `first_name`, `username`, `age`, `gender` etc. I want to write a query where I get average of age, just like normal SQL query:

`SELECT AVG(age) FROM Person`

But I have problem with creating this query in Peewee. I have:

`query = Person.select(fn.AVG(Person.age))`

When I print this query I get: `SELECT AVG("t1"."age") FROM "person" as "t1"` and when I iterate over query and and print I get `None`. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a scalar value, from an aggregate, you can use the scalar() method:

```
Person.select(fn.AVG(Person.age)).scalar()
```

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#aggregating-records